# spark jobserver failing to build with Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, spark-jobserver

I am trying to run spark-jobserver with spark-2.0 
I cloned branch spark-2.0-preview from github repository. I follow the deployment guide but when I try to deploy server using *bin/server_deploy.sh*. I got compilation error:

```
 Error:
[error] /spark-jobserver/job-server-extras/src/main/java/spark/jobserver/JHiveTestLoaderJob.java:4: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol: class DataFrame
[error] location: package org.apache.spark.sql
[error] import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
[error] /spark-jobserver/job-server-extras/src/main/java/spark/jobserver/JHiveTestJob.java:13: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.sql.Row[]
[error] return sc.sql(data.getString("sql")).collect();
[error] /spark-jobserver/job-server-extras/src/main/java/spark/jobserver/JHiveTestLoaderJob.java:25: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol: class DataFrame
[error] location: class spark.jobserver.JHiveTestLoaderJob
[error] final DataFrame addrRdd = sc.sql("SELECT * FROM default.test_addresses");
[error] /spark-jobserver/job-server-extras/src/main/java/spark/jobserver/JSqlTestJob.java:13: array required, but java.lang.Object found
[error] Row row = sc.sql("select 1+1").take(1)[0];
[info] /spark-jobserver/job-server-extras/src/main/java/spark/jobserver/JHiveTestJob.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] /spark-jobserver/job-server-extras/src/main/java/spark/jobserver/JHiveTestJob.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[error] (job-server-extras/compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
```

Did I forget to add some dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I found that it is bug because of changes in Spark API from 1.x to 2.x. you can found open issue on github https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/issues/760

I introduced some quick fix which for me solved the issue and I can deploy jobserver. I submitted pull request for that. https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/pull/762